# Entity Framework model binding/editor templates

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, asp.net-mvc-5

What the best way to get all tags for article in comma separated textbox in ASP.NET MVC View, redact them, click save and add new/existing or remove tags from editied article in "Edit" Action? DB Structire is simpliest:

Article:

```
ArticleID int
ArticleTitle varchar(50)
ArticleTags  varchar(MAX)
```

Tag:

```
TagID int
TagText varchar(20)
```

ArticleTag:

```
ArticleID int PK FK Article.ArticleID
TagID int PK FK Tag.TagID
```

I know that there is several ways like custom model binders or editor templates. But not sure if I'll write custom editor template and then scaffold, will it extract tags from textbox and that save for me, or I still need to write this logic.
I don't want to go with checkboxes, because if I will have 1000 tags later it will be quite hard to find correct tags, so textbox (like on StackOverflow) is best way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public ActionResult Create(Article article)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Articles.Add(article);
            db.SaveChanges();
            article = db.Articles.Include(x => x.Tags).Where(x => x.ArticleID == article.ArticleID).First();
            var Articleedtags = Request["Keywords"].Replace(", ", ",").Split(',').ToList();
            Articletags.ForEach(tag => Article.Tags.Add(db.Tags.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Text == tag) ?? db.Tags.Add(new Tag { Text = tag })));
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(Article);
    }
```